# .split() and [\\W] creates an additional empty string?

Tags: java, regex

I'm creating a small program to split a string into tokens (consecutive English alphabet characters, then outputting the number of tokens as well as the actual tokens. The problem is an extra empty string element is created wherever there is a comma followed by a space.

I've researched into regular expressions and understand that \W is anything that is not a word character.

```
String str = sc.nextLine();

// creating an array of tokens
String tokens[] = str.split("[\\W]");

int len = tokens.length;
System.out.println(len);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     System.out.println(tokens[i]);
  }
```

Input:

```
Hello, World.
```

Expected output:

```
2
Hello
World
```

Actual output:

```
3
Hello

World
```

Note: this is my first stack overflow post, if I've done anything wrong please let me know, thanks

Comment: It is correct. If you do not want empty strings, use `\w+` to match the tokens, or remove any initial non-word chars and then split with `\W+`: `s.replaceFirst("^\\W+", "").split("\\W+")`

Answer (score 1):

Try `str.split("\\W+")`
It means 1 or more non-word character

\W matches only 1 character. So it breaks at , and then breaks again at the space
That’s why it gives you back an extra empty string.
\W+ will match on ‘, ‘ as one, so it will break only once, so you will get back only the tokens. (It works on multiple tokens not just two. So ‘hello, world, again’ will give you [hello,world,again].

Comment: It worked, thank you. But why doesn't str.split("[\\W+]") not work?

Comment: [\\W+] matches a non world character or a + sign. You can use it like that also [\\W]+

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.split("\\W")` you will get empty items if:

- non-word char(s) appear(s) at the start of the string
- non-word chars appear in succession, one after another as `\W` matches 1 non-word char, breaks the string, and then the next non-word char breaks it again, producing empty strings.

There are two ways out.

Either remove all non-word chars at the start and then split with `\W+`:

```
String tokens[] = str.replaceFirst("^\\W+", "").split("\\W+");
```

Or, match the chunks of word chars with `\w+` pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("   abc=-=123");
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    tokens.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(tokens);
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/vTo0wK).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Scanner inputter = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter your thoughts : ");
final String words = inputter.nextLine();
final String[] tokens = words.split("\\W+");
Arrays.stream(tokens).forEach(System.out::println);
```